# Continuous, size-fixed, transparent graph in Gnuplot

Tags: python, gnuplot

Starting from this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from numpy import *
import Gnuplot as gp
import Gnuplot.funcutils

x = (1,2,3)
y=(2,4,5)
g = gp.Gnuplot()
d = gp.Data(x,y,with_="lines",title='Graph')
g.plot(d)
g('set size 200,100')
g.output('filename.svg')
```

I'd like to get a graph where points are connected to a line, dimension-fixed and transparent.
Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension-fixed"? What is supposed to be "transparent" (the line, the points)?

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the `g('set size 200,100')`.  This command basically tells gnuplot to make a plot that is 200 times bigger than normal in the x direction and 100 times bigger in the y direction -- when you make your plot it will either be **HUGE**, or you'll only actually get to see a very small portion of the plot in the corner (you probably won't see anything).

Next, here's how I would accomplish what you want in pure gnuplot (I think -- test it to see if I am indeed interpreting your request properly):

```
set terminal svg size 200,100
set output "filename.svg"
plot '-' w linespoints linestyle 1 pointtype 7 #just picked some linestyles and pointtypes... 
   1 2
   2 4
   3 5
   e
```

In order to put this into gnuplot-py, you could wrap it all up in g('...') -- This is a pretty ugly approach, but it should work.  I don't know what gnuplot-py recognizes as valid plot types and what it doesn't recognize...You'd probably have to dig into the source for that.

I've also used "inline data", but you could easily write your points to a temporary file (using the `tempfile` module and plot that instead if that's easier).

It seems like `d = gp.Data(x,y,with_="linespoints",title="data")` should work, but I make no promises...

My guess would also be that `g.output('filename.svg',terminal='svg',size="200,100")` might work, but I never really like gnuplot-py because it doesn't seem to behave the way I think it should.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to resort to a g('...') before plotting.

In summary, what happens if you try this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from numpy import *
import Gnuplot as gp
import Gnuplot.funcutils

x = (1,2,3)
y=(2,4,5)
g = gp.Gnuplot()
d = gp.Data(x,y,with_="linespoints",title='Graph')
g("set terminal svg size 200,100")
g("set output 'filename.svg'")
g.plot(d)
```

Comment: Perfect, it works like I want. 
Now, to get it transparent (I'd like just the graph, whit no white background), how can I do? 
I tried to set another property:
`g("set transparent")` but I get: 

`Unrecognized option.  See 'help set'.`

And, second, can you "report" me a good guide which I can follow in order to customize my graph? (I'd like to use subplots or at least various plots of multiple data)

Comment: My .pngs usually turn out transparent if I have gnuplot create an .eps and then I convert it to .png using `convert output.eps -rotate 90 output.png` (it usually turns out rotated for me).

Comment: @FrankBr : Some terminals will give you transparent plots by default.  `eps`,`ps`, `svg` all do transparent backgrounds by default.  to get a transparent png, you can convert as recommended by andyras in the comment, or, if your gnuplot supports it, you can do `set term pngcairo transparent` (instead of `set terminal svg` above).  As far as customization, it really depends on what you want to do.  to put multiple graphs on one plot, gnuplot provides `set multiplot`.  to put multiple lines on one graph, there's `replot`.

Comment: @mgilson I don't get a transparent image by dafault (executing your code).

Answer (score 0):

I never imported gnuplot into python but in the gnuplot shell i do it like this, when i want additional lines in the plot:

```
    set arrow from 1,2 to 2,4 nohead lw 2
    set arrow from 2,4 to 3,5 nohead lw 2
```

Use unset arrow to remove them again. Your line g('set size 200,100') suggests that you can pass lines to gnuplot to do this.

What is the result when you run your code? Don't you get the data plotted and connected with lines?
I have no idea what you mean with dimension-fixed and transparent.

Comment: This quickly becomes cumbersome for multiple lines ... why not just put the coordinates in a file and plot with lines and again with points -- or (maybe better) with linespoints?

Comment: linespoints sounds like what he wants to have, plotting twice would work in the code like d2 = gp.Data(x,y,with_="points",title="data")
g.plot(d,d2). The set arrow is add connections between any points, but not good to connect points of a data series

Comment: @mgilson I read about linespoints, but how do I use it?
What I coded above is just a little part of a script wich has to work in "real time". Putting some coords, afer got them (necessary, 'cause I need them in a different code point), may increase delay in computation of charts.

Comment: @Schuh Exactly what I need.
And I'd want an image wich I decide size (in pixel) and transparent because I don't wanna get the withe background.

Comment: To use linespoints just try d = gp.Data(x,y,with_="linespoints",title="data") g.plot(d) For the transparence you could try to configure the gnuplot terminal you use, e.g. try "set terminal png transparent size 200,100"

Comment: Understood. What I get is an image which is formed by a series of grey-black squares.

Comment: @FrankBr -- do you see a plot?  The checkerboard pattern you might be describing is the indicator that the image *is transparent* in many image viewing programs (Eye of the Gnome for me on Ubuntu Linux).  To get rid of the checkerboard, you need to put the image over something.

Comment: Yeah, I know that means transparent, but I've no setted up that property in my code. What I get now is a "rotated graph".